# TFS-git single repository can have two different solution file?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

Initially, we were having two different TFS-git repositories for two different projects with there different solution file, till now everything is working fine.
Today, my manager came and told us that we will be having a single repository in that we have to add all the projects (means 2 projects will have 2 solutions file). For this, I have cloned that single repository with my local folder and placed my two different projects in it. After this in my changes/commit option no file showing for commit.

[Two folders are present in the image, each folder contains all the project & solution file in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue7UB.png)

[Service Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWyxF.png)

[Web Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2ihp.png)

[No file showing to commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyfjL.png)

[After adding 2 projects in the repository and commit, the only folder gets committed and no file under it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vEPV.png)

Comment: How did you add your solutions? Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the steps below:

1. Create a new empty repository in TFS.
2. Connect to this Repo in VS/Team Explorer and clone this repo to your local folder.
3. Add the two solutions/projects in the local folder, then you should see the changes in VS/Team Explorer.